# If $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}^n, \exists y \in A, d(x,y) = \inf\{d(x,a) \mid a \in A \}$, A is a closed set in $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Tags: general-topology

Let $\mathbb{R}^n$ has Euclidean distance $d: \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$.

(a) $\mathrm{A} \neq \emptyset$ is a closed set in $\mathbb{R}^n$

(b) $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}^n, \exists y \in A, d(x,y) = \inf\{d(x,a) \mid a \in A\} $

I trying to prove that (a) and (b) are equivalent.

the proof of (a) to (b) is suggested in other questions, but I think (b) to (a) is not proved.

please give me some ideas to prove (b) to (a)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $A$ is *not* closed, take $x\in\overline A\setminus A$. Then $d(x,A)=0$, but there is not $a\in A$ such that $d(x,a)=0$.

Comment: Do you recognise that you closed the same question as a duplicate not even an hour ago?

Comment: @AsafKaragila Sorry, I am not unfamilier this pages, and don't recognise that... I delete another question.

Comment: @José Carlos Santos Wow, it is so simple...The reason of unexist of a is that x is not in A, it's correct ?

Comment: @mikecat Yes, that is correct.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Yes, I noticed it. The question that I closed as a duplicate asked for a proof of an equivalence. I closed it as a duplicate of two questions which proved the hardest to prove implication. This time, the poster acknowledged that that implication had been proved before and asked for a proof of the other implication. This is an interesting situation. Was I right when I closed the other question as a duplicate? Or should I have voted to close it because it needed more focus (after all, it consisted of two questions).

Comment: @AsafKaragila As a facts, I didn't recognise that and the question didn't focus on one thing, so I think your judge is right.